# Opposite of target manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, manifolds

I am not sure if this is the right place to aski this question, but assume we have two manifolds $M,N$ and a function

$$u: M \rightarrow N$$

We can then refer to $N$ as the 'target manifold'. How can we call $M$ in those cases? The only thing I can think of is 'start manifold' but this doesn't sound right.

(Sorry, I am no a native english speaker.)

Comment: I would call $M$ domain of $u$ and $N$ codomain of $u$.

Comment: The term opposite to "target manifold" would be "source manifold"

Comment: Thank you very much!